# Twitter access token URI has empty return in C based OAuth attempt

Tags: c, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to work through some C code using liboauth to sign in to Twitter.  I've created an application within twitter, and have managed the first couple of steps.  I've received my request token/secret and verification URL, and then used that URL to get my PIN.

The next step is to send a request to https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token to retrieve my access token/secret.  I've added my PIN as my oauth_verifier.  Try as I might, I'm getting no response from the server at all.

In C I have:

```
    sprintf(tmpURI, "%s&oauth_verifier=%d", accessTokenURI, pin);
    req_url = oauth_sign_url2(tmpURI, &postarg, 
              OA_HMAC, NULL, consumerKey,
              consumerSecret, requestToken,
              requestTokenSecret);
    reply = oauth_http_post(req_url, postarg);
```

I can replicate this issue using command line cURL as follows (my keys, PIN and such are obfuscated):

```
curl -d "oauth_consumer_key=CONKEY&oauth_nonce=NONCE&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1299967688&oauth_token=OAUTHTOKEN&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=OAUTHSIG&oauth_verfier=PIN" https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token
```

As far as I can tell, this call is supposed to result in a response that provides my access tokens, but I'm getting nothing - not even an error message of any sort.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, so I was being very stupid on this one.  I was using the same PIN with a different request token & secret.